# Splitting lines read from file into array of key-value pairs in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a txt file with N key-value pairs:

```
key_1=val_1
key_2=val_2
key_N=val_N
```

I need to read this file and set those to an array:

```
Attributes = [
    {key_1, val_1},
    {key_2, val_2},
    {key_N, val_N}],
```

I've tried a couple of different approaches but none was successful, the closest I got was the following:

```
{ok, FileAttributes} = file:read_file("/data/file-attributes.txt"),
string:split(FileAttributes, "=", all)
```

But when I print this I get:

```
key_1val_1
key_2val_2
key_Nval_N
```

How would be the best way to read the `file-attributes.txt` and split keys and values into items of the Attributes array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a txt file with N key-value pairs:
>
> ```
> key_1=val_1
> key_2=val_2
> key_N=val_N
> ```
>
> I need to read this file and set those to an array:
>
> ```
> Attributes = [
>     {key_1, val_1},
>     {key_2, val_2},
>     {key_N, val_N}],
> ```

```
make_array(FileName) ->
    case file:read_file(FileName) of
        {ok, Bin} ->
            Lines = binary:split(Bin, <<"\n">>, [trim, global]),
            Array = make_tuples(Lines, []),
            io:format("Result=~n~p~n", [Array]);
        {error, Reason} ->
            io:format("[Me] There was an error:~n~w", [Reason])
    end.

make_tuples([Line|Lines], Acc) ->
    io:format("Line= -->~s<--~n", [Line]),
    [Left, Right] = binary:split(Line, <<"=">>),
    io:format("Term={~s, ~s}~n", [Left, Right]),
    make_tuples(Lines, [{Left, Right}|Acc]);
make_tuples([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc).
```

--output:--

```
58> c(a).                               
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

59> a:make_array("file-attributes.txt").
Line= -->key_1=val_1<--
Term={key_1, val_1}
Line= -->key_2=val_2<--
Term={key_2, val_2}
Line= -->key_N=val_N<--
Term={key_N, val_N}
Result=
[{<<"key_1">>,<<"val_1">>},
 {<<"key_2">>,<<"val_2">>},
 {<<"key_N">>,<<"val_N">>}]
ok
```

Comment: You can use `bin_to_list()` anytime you think it's appropriate to convert the binaries to strings (erlang strings are always a list of integers despite what the shell may output).

Comment: QQ. Do I need the `make_tuples([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc).`?

Comment: @JulianoCosta, Does the program work without it?   You certainly don't have to reverse the `ACC` list, you can just return it.

Comment: Great I was just wondering if it had any other goal there.
BTW, does `Acc` stands for something?
Coming from a Java background, naming conventions are really different here :D

Comment: @JulianoCosta,  In recursive languages, you have to have a way of stopping the recursion.  That is done by defining another function clause, which in this case matches the empty list, so that when the list of of Lines is empty, the recursion stops.   Note there is no recursive call in the second function clause.  If you did not have that second clause, then when the list of Lines is empty, the first function clause would not match,  because it matches at list with at least one element, and the program would crash.

Comment: @JulianoCosta,  `Acc` is an abbreviation for `Accumulator`, and it is a variable that accumulates the results that you want to ultimately return from the function.  The first function clause adds results to the front of the  `Acc` list.  When the recursion finally ends, you want to return the results.  The results stored in `Acc` will be in reverse order, however, so if order matters, then you need to reverse the list.  You could add  each result to the end of the  `Acc` list, however that is very inefficient, so adding to the front of a list, then reversing is the way things are done.

Comment: @JulianoCosta, You will discover that the matching in the head of multiple function clauses is the most powerful tool in erlang.  It is similar to a series of if statements: depending on which function clause matches, different code in the various function clauses will execute.  But the matching is more powerful than an if statement because you can dissect the function arguments anyway you want, so that the pieces you are interested in get assigned to variables.  I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1):

Matching example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go([{1, Y, Z}=Tuple | Tuples]) ->
    io:format("~w -> 2nd + 3rd = ~w~n", [Tuple, Y+Z]),
    go(Tuples);
go([{X, 2, Z}=Tuple | Tuples]) ->
    io:format("~w -> 1st + 3rd = ~w~n", [Tuple, X+Z]),
    go(Tuples);
go([{X, Y, 3}=Tuple | Tuples]) ->
    io:format("~w -> 1st + 2nd = ~w~n", [Tuple, X+Y]),
    go(Tuples);
go([{X, Y, Z}=Tuple | Tuples]) ->
    io:format("~w -> Sum = ~w~n", [Tuple, X+Y+Z]),
    go(Tuples);
go([]) -> all_done.

test() ->
    go([
        {1, 2, 3},
        {3, 2, 1},
        {3, 4, 3},
        {10, 20, 30}
       ]).
```

--output:--

```
14> c(a).    
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

15> a:test().
{1,2,3} -> 2nd + 3rd = 5
{3,2,1} -> 1st + 3rd = 4
{3,4,3} -> 1st + 2nd = 7
{10,20,30} -> Sum = 60
all_done
```

A list with one element can be written as:

```
[ 4 | [] ]
```

So, if you have the following function clause:

```
go( [Head|Tail] ) -> 
    %% do stuff with Head
    go(Tail).
```

and call:

```
g([4]).
```

erlang will assign `4` to `Head` and the empty list, `[]`, to `Tail`.  But, when Tail is the empty list, the call to `go(Tail)` will not match that function clause, causing the program to crash.

Also, note that unlike in Java, a function head can use a mix of constants and variables for the parameters.

Comment: wow... What a lesson! Really appreciate the effort you put to explain that to me. I have to confess that I had to read a couple of times to get the idea. Thanks again @7stud!